# Дано n целых чисел. Найти среднее арифметическое положительных элементов с четной суммой цифр, до и после которых расположены отрицательные

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Написала программу, но не могу понять, в чем ошибка

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, k = 0, a, c, f, b, sr,sum=0;
    cout << "Input n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Input a and b" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> c;
        int s = 0, temp = a;

        if (a < 0 && b>0 && c<0)
        {
            while (a > 0)
            {
                f = a % 10;
                s += c;
                a /= 10;
            }
            if (s % 2 == 0) k++;
        }
        a = b;
        sum+=temp;
    }
    sr = temp/k;
    cout << sr;
}
```

подскажите, пожалуйста, как привести программу в рабочее состояние?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, на каждой итерации цикла, вы сдвигаете только одну переменную, а надо две

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> c;
        ...
        a = b;
        b = c; // надо добавить
    }
```

Во-вторых, подсчет суммы вы делаете на каждой итерации цикла, а надо только тогда, когда выполняются условия проверки на отрицательные числа до и после и на четную сумму цифр

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (a < 0 && b>0 && c<0)
        {
            if (s % 2 == 0) 
            {  k++;
               sum+=temp;
            }
        }
        sum+=temp;
    }
```

В-третьих внутренний цикл `while` никогда не выполняется

```
if (a < 0 && b>0 && c<0) // если a<0
{
    while (a > 0)  // пока a>0
    {
    }
}
```

В четвертых сумму цифр нужно проверять у переменной `b`, т.к. только она положительная

```
if (a < 0 && b>0 && c<0)
```

Есть ещё и в-пятых, и в-шестых, и в...
Но с таким количеством косяков и некомпилирующимся кодом уже бессмысленно смотреть дальше.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Поняла, буду исправлять!